# How to run or execute an SKAction from outside of the object?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, sprite-kit, skaction

I have some code like following:

```
-(void) createBall {

    _ballSprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"ball0001"];
    _ballSprite.position = CGPointMake(firstNode.position.x, firstNode.position.y);
     SKAction *ballScale =[SKAction scaleXTo:-0.5 duration:0];
     SKAction *ballMove = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-300 duration:0];
     SKAction *ballMoveScale = [SKAction sequence:@[ballScale,ballMove];
     SKAction *ballScaleMove = [SKAction sequence:@[ballMove,ballScale]; //Unused variable
     [_ballSprite runAction:ballMoveScale];
     [self addChild:_ballSprite];

}
```

Now how do I run let say ballScaleMove from out side eg. inside the touchBegan handler or at initWithSize ..etc.?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

///here maybe
[_ballSprite runAction:ballScaleMove];  // Error undeclare identifier 'ballScaleMove';


}
```

Comment: `KAction` is not a valid class. Did you mean `SKAction`? Please copy/paste **exactly** the code you are currently having issues with, so we can more accurately diagnose your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your properties or iVars as global.   define them in the @interface of your class

```
@interface
@property Class *myProperty;
@end
```

Then you can access them with self.myProperty or _myProperty (accessing the implicit iVar for your property)

I hope it helps

Comment: looking at my codes, I have already got SKSpriteNode*_ballSprite; but do u mean I should have something like SKAction*_ballScaleMove too? I don't have problem accessing _ballSprite globally but the Actions wouldn't work.

Comment: Not clear why the down vote...  The ballScaleMove object is declared  and instantiated in the createBall method. to access it in the touchesBegan method, it should be a global property or iVar.   Did I miss something?.... e

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
     SKAction *ballScale =[SKAction scaleXTo:-0.5 duration:0];
     SKAction *ballMove = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:-300 duration:0];
     SKAction *ballMoveScale = [SKAction sequence:@[ballScale,ballMove];
    [_ballSprite runAction:ballScaleMove]; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andrey, but the actual sequence is a lot more than this sample.this is a simplified version, following your method would mean, duplicating a lot of code here and there, I need an easy way to replace actions.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented a Singleton object which returns all SKActions I need. This approach has also the advantage to reuse the SKActions